# How to quickly find points of interest (waypoints, entries, quests zones) in the randomly generated areas?

Tags: path-of-exile

If you have a look at the [main map of any act](http://www.pathofexile.com/areas) (<kbd>U</kbd> by default), you can notice that areas are oriented.  For instance, in the first act's main map, [Tidal Island](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Tidal_Island) is south of [Terraces](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Terraces).  And indeed, I've always found Terraces at the far south of the Tidal Island area.

Same goes for some other areas, like in Act 2: the [Tree Roots](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/The_Root_of_the_Problem) recovering the [Vaal Ruins](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Vaal_Ruins_Level_1)' entry is always somewhere at the north of the [River Crossings](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/River_Crossings) area.

[image: Tree Roots]

Is there some kind of constraint on the orientation of the points of interest during the generation of an area ?  Is it possible to use it to buy some time while looking for something specific in an area (a waypoint, for example) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. You just have to learn where things are located in each area.

A few examples:

- The entry to Fetid Pool is always located in the north-west of Mud
  Flats.
- The waypoint in Dark Forest is always somewhere along the road, so
  just follow it.
- The Crematorium is always located in the north-west of Sarn Slums.

Maybe they are not always in the same location, but they have been every time for me and i think it is fixed for many zone entries and waypoints.

Comment: A few points are fixed or almost fixed; in the closed beta there were even more than now -even area exits were pretty fixed. But almost everything is just random.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Btw: why is it a community wiki answer ?

Comment: @Anto Great question... seems my mind was wandering when i submitted the answer...

Comment: Haha :)  Sh*t happens !